# No IP address on Windows SBS 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, ip, windows-sbs-2008

We have a strange problem in our Windows SBS 2008 and it just came over a night.
The problem is that Windows says that we are not connected to any IP4 or IP6 network but it recognises that the network cable is plugged in.

The server is Domain Controller, DNS and DHCP server.

Things we have tested

1. Uninstall the NIC and installed the latest driver from the manufacturer
2. Reset both winsock and ip settings by using netsh command
3. Installed a new Network card (PCI), still the same problem.
4. Tested the network cable in another computer.
5. Upgraded the BIOS
6. Many restarts
7. Test both manual IP address and auto (the auto does not get the default 169)
8. New router

Please check the following pictures
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

OS is Windows 2008 (not R2)
If you see above, the command ipconfig /all does not get any IP address information at all.

Any clue, someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be running the "Connect to the Internet" & "Setup your Internet address"

SBS is very picky with people not running their wizards.

Comment: Thx for answer. Already tested, without result.

Answer (score 1):

Run the [Fix My Network Wizard](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2008/11/26/introduction-to-the-fix-my-network-wizard-fncw.aspx). SBS is a different beast, and must be appeased with different tactics than other Windows Server beasts. Usually on SBS it involves wizards. The Fix My Network wizard runs through many of the things that you've already done, and more, all from a SBS-specific vantage point.

If that doesn't work, I suspect some kind of corruption in a system file that networking is reliant on. Check out running [sfc /scannow](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491008.aspx). Make sure an installation disc is nearby to pull clean systems files from if the utility needs them.

Comment: Thx for answer. Already tested, without result.

Comment: @anpe Did you run `sfc` with the `/offbootdir` and `/offwindir` options set? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserversetup/thread/cd3d665f-3d95-4617-946d-55d8c03448fe/